support for strong consistency in memgraph
Does memgraph's Java client support strong consistency? I know that neo4j supports a variation called bookmarks. Does memgraph also support this? I looked at the memgraph documentation and could not find anything in this regard.

Memgraph does not have a Java client. It depends on a Neo4j Java client. So you can use the same client for both Memgraph and Neo4j.
Since strong consistency is a general term in concurrent and distributed environments, I will comment on both.

In a concurrent context, Memgraph provides a snapshot isolation level by default. More info in this blog post. Neo4j, by default, has a lower isolation level, read
commited.This means lower consistency in a concurrent environment.

In a distributed (clustering) environment context, Memgraph is
eventually consistent database. Neo4j uses bookmarks to be casual consistent which is a stronger level of consistency, but it is not strongly consistent.


Memgraph currently does not support Neo4j Bookmarks implementation.
